# Showing error while importing Sceneform Assets

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I get this error While import Sceneform asset. I've added the

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0
}
```

in the Project level gradle file this also

```
dependencies {
implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0"
}
```

I searched alot but getting this error 
[image]

Comment: Are all model files imported into the project ? . Looks like some texture files are missing.

Comment: I added a new model with that size error and texture are fixed but matc: returned error remained the same

Answer (score 0):

You should import the models manually using this format in the project gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'

sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/andy.obj', // 'Source Asset Path' specified during import.
        'default',                            // 'Material Path' specified during import.
        'sampledata/models/andy.sfa',         // '.sfa Output Path' specified during import.
        'src/main/res/raw/andy')              // '.sfb Output Path' specified during import.
```

As shown here: https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/import-assets